# PHP script fails when launched through crontab ("Directory nonexistent")

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I have a PHP script creating a MySQL dump, working perfectly when launched from the browser. It calls mysqldump through the exec() function.

I scheduled this PHP script as **root** in the crontab (on an Ubuntu VPS). It fails with the following error message :

> sh: 1: cannot create ./backups/db_20220522.sql: Directory nonexistent

I have set_include_path('/var/www/mysite.com/'); at the beginning of my PHP script. The script and the "backups" directory are in there.

What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Can you post your code? We can't really help you if we don't see any logic.

Comment: cron runs as a different user and from a different working directory to the code when run from a browser and therefore via apache

Comment: If I strip the unnecessary lines :
$sqlFile = "./backups/db_".date("Ymd").".sql";
$createBackup = "mysqldump --host=$dbServer --user=$user --password=$password $dbName > $sqlFile";
exec($createBackup, $log, $return);

Answer (score 0):

You need the specify the full path to your backup directory in your script .
Cron runs from a different directory.

eg

```
/home/username/domains/domain.com/public_html/backup
```

Comment: I did not mention it (my mistake) but I already have a line set_include_path('/var/www/mysite.com/'); at the beginning of my PHP script. The script and "backups" directory are in there (/var/www/mysite.com/backups/), do you understand in this case why the relative path fails ?